# Python, initialize class attribute in loop

Tags: python, loops, class, instance

How can I initialize the attributes of a class instance in a loop? Below example explains what I want to do. Imagine a class with twenty to thirty attributes. There must be an efficient way to set values. Do I have to change my class attributes in a dictionary to do so? But this would be a problem since I am working with the Django framework to create the table with the class in this example. Thanks in advance!

```
class Foo():
    fieldA = float()
    fieldB = float()
    fieldC = float()
    fieldD = float()
    fieldE = float()
    fieldF = float()
    # several more field elements


def main():
    foo_instance = Foo()

    # open here excel file with openpyxl library
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(BASE_DIR + file, read_only=True, data_only=True)
    ws = wb['sheet1']


    # I would like to iterate through the instance 
    for i in range(1,20):
        foo.fieldA = float(ws['A{}'.format(i)]) #how to iterate through the attributes from foo instance?

    '''
        This is the inefficient way:
        foo.fieldA = float(ws['A1'])
        foo.fieldB = float(ws['A2'])
        foo.fieldC = float(ws['A3'])
        foo.fieldD = float(ws['A4'])
        foo.fieldE = float(ws['A5'])
        etc.
    '''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the variables in a list and iterating through them.

```
my_list = [fieldA, fieldB] # and so on...

# Set an index
index = 0

# Iterate
for field in my_list:
    field = float(ws['A{}'.format(index)])
    index += 1 # Increment index each time
```

You could even drop the variable names and just use list indices like `my_list[0]`, `my_list[1]` etc, but this would depend on what you need.

Comment: fieldA, fieldB are attributes from a class. And I also can't generate a list within the class as that would not create tables in the Django framework. I feel I have to create a function within the class to make the attributes iterable. Is there not a better way?

Comment: I could get the attributes of the class in a list but I dont know how to access it: members = [attr for attr in dir(foo) if not callable(getattr(foo, attr)) and not attr.startswith('__')]

Comment: @ErcanDogan If you have control of the class, you could make the list an attribute of the class as well. Also, lists are generally the preferred way to iterate over variables. There is ways to do messy things like turning strings with an incrementing number into variable names, but I believe that is not considered good practice. When you come to use the Django table, you can easily extract variables from the list anyway, or pass the list around as a reference.

Comment: @ErcanDogan I believe you can access an instance’s variables with `foo.__dict__.keys()`

Comment: Hi Chris, the foo.__dict__.keys() provides me strings of keys and only those which are declared as self.xyz not the local attributes.